# How to place a RecyclerView above BottomAppBar wrapped with CoordinatorLayout in Kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have Bottom navigationView and wraped it with BottomAppBar and there is a FAB in stick the middle. I Can't put my frameLayout which is recycleview in to the up of the bottomUpbar. And I can't change it to constraintlayout because bottomUpbar must wrap with the coordinatorlayout.(Kotlin)

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="0dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" >


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/custom_botnav"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/custom_botnav"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/PrimeOrange"
        android:contentDescription="tomboladd"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
        app:fabCustomSize="73dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        app:maxImageSize="45dp"
        app:tint="@color/PrimeGreen" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```